# Post IInvokeActivity from root bot to Skill bot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-language-understanding

I have a root bot which is hosted on Microsoft teams channel.
An OAuthCard is displayed on Teams channel as shown below:

[image]

we are using below given line to send any incoming activity to Skill bot:

```cs
    // route the activity to the skill
    var response = await _skillClient.PostActivityAsync(_configuration["MicrosoftAppId"], targetSkill, _skillsConfig.SkillHostEndpoint, (Activity)turnContext.Activity, cancellationToken);
```

When we click on **Login** button TeamsActivityHandler generates **IInvokeActivity**, but I am not able to pass control to Skill bot again due to PostActivityAsync Method only accepts **IMessageActivity**.

Is there a way to Convert or Post IInvokeActivity to Skill bot?

Answer (score 0):

If you look again at the `PostActivityAsync()`'s signature, you'll actually see that **it takes an *`Activity`* type**, not an `IMessageActivity`.

```cs
public async Task<InvokeResponse> PostActivityAsync(string fromBotId, BotFrameworkSkill toSkill, Uri callbackUrl, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Looking at [`Activity`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Schema/ActivityEx.cs#L22), you can see that Activity implements all of the Activity types, allowing you to cast them back and forth without issue

```cs
    public partial class Activity :
        IActivity,
        IConversationUpdateActivity,
        IContactRelationUpdateActivity,
        IInstallationUpdateActivity,
        IMessageActivity,
        IMessageUpdateActivity,
        IMessageDeleteActivity,
        IMessageReactionActivity,
        ISuggestionActivity,
        ITypingActivity,
        IEndOfConversationActivity,
        IEventActivity,
        IInvokeActivity,
        ITraceActivity,
        IHandoffActivity { // ... }
```

Additionally if you look at `IInvokeActivity`

```cs
public interface IInvokeActivity : IActivity
```

It implements `IActivity`, which specifies that classes implementing it must have `IInvokeActivity AsInvokeActivity();`.

---

**So to answer your question, when you pass your `IInvokeActivity` into `PostActivityAsync()`, use the `AsInvokeActivity()` method to convert it to an InvokeActivity.**

```cs
await _skillClient.PostActivityAsync(_botId, targetSkill, _skillsConfig.SkillHostEndpoint, (Activity)turnContext.Activity.AsInvokeActivity(), cancellationToken);
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion you gave and added AsInvokeActivity() but HTTP response is received as 501.

Comment: Can you update your post to include the error stack? There is not enough information to help debug further, as it does not appear to be breaking at the PostActivityAsync() top layer (can accept IInvokeActivity), but seems to be breaking further in